# How to get my jsonResult to return a complex json return?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a linq query that returns data and that is working great but i am unable to return the data to the browser.  It throws this incredibly awful error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have gotten this error times before, but i haven't found how to solve and more importantly why it happens.

This is my query:

```
var query = (from c in db.Responses
   join d in db.ResponseDetails on c.ResponseId equals d.ResponseId
   join f in db.UserProfiles on c.UserProfile.UserId equals f.UserId
           where c.QuestionId == id && f.UserId.Equals(userid)
   select new TeamForecastHistory { Id = d.ResponseId,
                               Reason = c.Reason,
                               UserName = f.UserName,
                               DateCreated = c.DateCreated,
                               Values = (from l in db.ResponseDetails 
                                      where l.ResponseId == id
                                      select (int) l.ResponseDetailVal*100  ).ToList()
                            }).ToList();
```

Here is my model that I want to send the data back in:

```
public class TeamForecastHistory
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Userid { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
            public string Reason { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public List<int> Values { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: { input: 'history', id: test },
         url: "/Forecaster/GetPartialview/"
          }).done(function (data) {
             $("#mydiv").html(data);
       });
```

**Update**

Following john's advice I changed the model a bit, now instead of `List<int>` it is `IEnumrable<int> Values`.  This returns data and isn't giving an error, but it's not returning the data of Values either: (here is the return data, this is representative of the dataset)

```
0:{
    DateCreated: "/Date(1389222371636)/"
    Id: 122
    Reason: "Reason#1"
    UserName: "jsteve"
    Userid: 0
    Values: []
}
```

**Update**

The last update mentioned the values variable not having any data being returned, this was due to the subquery using the wrong id in the where clause.  The complete code that works is listed below:

```
var query = (from c in db.Responses
         join d in db.ResponseDetails on c.ResponseId equals d.ResponseId
         join f in db.UserProfiles on c.UserProfile.UserId equals f.UserId
         where c.QuestionId == id && f.UserId.Equals(userid)
         select new TeamForecastHistory { Id = d.ResponseId,
                                     Reason = c.Reason,
                                     UserName = f.UserName,
                                     DateCreated = c.DateCreated,
                                     Values = (from l in db.ResponseDetails 
                                              where l.ResponseId == d.ResponseId
                                              select l.ResponseDetailVal*100  )
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Just leave off the ToList.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If I leave the toList off then it says:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'System.Array'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I don't see an array anywhere. Try making the `Values` property of type `IEnumerable<int>`, then you shouldn't need the `.ToList()` on the `Values=`.

Comment: This just means that the subquery returns no rows

Comment: @JohnSaunders ya, it was a silly mistake in the where clause of the subquery.  I meant to put d.responseid instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to execute the inner ToList on the database. And SQL server doesn't know how to do that. You could try fetching just the data and then building your output model after fetching the results.